# If button appear - Activate it

Tags: javascript, button, loading

I make in ajax a load more button. Everything works fine.

```
<div class="videos-ajax-paging load-more">
<button 
 data-current_page="2" 
 data-category="cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4" 
 type="button" 
 class="video-ajax-load-more">+</button>
</div>
```

I am looking for a possibility to "activate" the button if it appears on the screen.

No Jquery, only in simple Javascript. You think it's possible ? Can you help ?

Big thanks

Comment: What do you mean by `activate`?

Comment: Do you mean to click on it if it appears?

Comment: Yes @ShioT, the condition is "if it appears", activate the button.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the button on the returned ajax
Add id to the button
and then call:

```
var button = document.getElementById("x");
button.click();
```

Comment: I'm restricted and can't use ID. I test this `var button = document.getElementsByClassName("video-ajax-load-more");
button.click();` but it doesn't work :-/

Comment: your button is array of elements, so try: `button[0].click();`

Answer (score 0):

whatever your activation logic means, I have prepared a short fiddle for you.

```js
function activate() { 
  if (!document.getElementsByClassName('video-ajax-load-more').length) {
   setTimeout(function() { activate(); }, 100);
   return;
  }
  var element = document.getElementsByClassName('video-ajax-load-more')[0];
  
  // do your activation logic e.g. alert it
  alert(element);
}


setTimeout(function() { activate(); }, 100);
```

```html
<div class="videos-ajax-paging load-more">
<button data-current_page="2" data-category="cat1,cat2,cat3,cat4" type="button" class="video-ajax-load-more">+</button>
</div>
```